# How to get multiple SQL Tables structure (T-SQL) into excel sheet?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to take 198 SQL Tables structures. Normally, I know about `SP_HELP` and `ALT+F1` to get single table structure.

How can i get structure multiple tables? If i provide list of table names, output should be structure(Table name(field name, Data type, Length)) of all those tables.

I have only **read access** to SQL DB.
And, I am new to SQL.

**Environment details:**

**Client Tool:** Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014

I have searched in SO, there are answers for single table. But, that doesn't solve my question.

Comment: SSMS isn't an IDE, it's a client tool. It's no different than Excel in that respect.

Comment: Does this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18059/copy-complete-structure-of-a-table) help? I got it from Stack Exchange...

Comment: @Birel - No. Shnugo, have given me right answer. If possible, upvote the question, it will useful for others future reference.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will return a list of all tables and their columns with a lot of details about data_type, size, nullability and so on:

```sql
USE YourDatabaseNameHere;
SELECT t.TABLE_TYPE, c.*
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON t.TABLE_SCHEMA=c.TABLE_SCHEMA 
                                      AND  t.TABLE_NAME=c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'; --With 'VIEW' you'd find views, or just omit the WHERE...
```

You can use a simple Excel to connect to the database and read this result into a Sheet.

### UPDATE

Did not read, that you can use SSMS. Just paste the query into a new query window and execute it. The result can be *copy-pasted* into excel...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am pasting list of table name in where condition as `TABLE_NAME in (list of tables)`. That will solve my issue. Don't why my question is down voted. Your solution is not present in previous SO Question. Your query save lot of time, Thanks again.

Comment: @shaikmoeed I'm glad to help you. The *Uiehhh, it's a duplicate*-police is - sometimes rather harsh... ;-)

Comment: I am getting length of some fields as NULL. From `sys.columns` table `max_length` field is showing length for all, But don't know, how to join `sys.columns` with present using `information_schema` tables. Can you please help?

Comment: It's showing `NULL` for data types like `int, bigint, datetime, smalldatetimes`. For `image` data type it's showing wrong length like `1462732`. please help!

Comment: @shaikmoeed What do you expect? The size of the datatypes mentioned is fix (int=4, bigint=8...) and image is deprecated for centuries... The approach above brings back variable length defined by the user (e.g. `VARCHAR(100)`). A datatype's size can be seen in `sys.types`, but there are rather tricky computations in some cases. Another prospective  is the length of the actual content (see `LEN()`). And btw: Next time please do not un-accept an answer (is seen as impolite). Rather start a new question with a link to this one.

Comment: @Shnugo- yes, you are right. I know that there are default lengths to those data types. For my project estimations, your query solved my issue. When i'm actually started working, those NULL values are disturbing, where i again need to copy structure one by one. Sorry for un-accept of your answer. Present i have solved by joining `sys.columns`, `sys.types`, `sys.tables` tables. This is gives me exactly what i required!

Comment: @shaikmoeed no problem, glad that you found a solution! Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use DB Schema tool, which is used to design the database and understand the existing relational database mapping.

Comment: Can you tell me clearly? with that, can i get all tables structure?

Comment: https://www.dbschema.com/index.html, just connect your database with it. Existing schema will be loaded with relationship over tool.

Answer (score 1):

**By using SQL Server 2008 R2**
This will create a script for you then you will be able to run it on other sql server it will create the same Data Base with all talbes.

1. Right Click On Data Base Name
2. Go to Task
3. Go to Generate
   Scripts [SQL Server 2008 R2 DataBase Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXxku.png)
4. Next > Next > Next > SetYourPath Next > Finish

[first Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7SyH.png)  [second Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tPH3.png)  [3rd Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD8CE.png)  [4th Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upNal.png)  [5th Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO5Rq.png)

Comment: How will that get the table structure into excel sheet ?